# Typescript: delete multiple keys looping array

Tags: typescript

I have an object

```
const person = {
  first: 'John',
  last: 'Doe',
  id: 1,
}
```

I want to delete keys from person object. So in JavaScript it works

```
['first', 'last'].forEach((i) => {
  delete person[i]
})
```

**Error**(From editor VSCode not compiled)

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{ first: string; last: string; id: number; }'.
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type '{ first: string; last: string; id: number; }'.ts(7053)
```

But in TypeScript it shows error. What will be the equivalent code in TypeScript. Thanks.

Comment: What is the shown error?

Comment: @MoxxiManagarm I have added error. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
const keysToDelete: (keyof typeof person)[] = ['first', 'last'] 

keysToDelete.forEach((i) => {
   delete person[i]
})
```

You need to let TS know you are only using the keys of `person` and not just arbitrary strings

[TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBADgUwE4XDAvDA3gKBjAMwEsUoAuGAcgCkQALMSgGjxgBsBDaCygERATNWRACYUAjCwC+OHKEiwA1ggCeEACoheCNgigIKACmUqQBGFBWIz8ZKjABKANoBdDDCeVipZlU7RKN1kTDS0dPQQAOgIQJABRDmA6Q0MiBwwAPmxWEXD9WxRwJyIXHCkHIA)

Comment: I will request thedude to add a little description if possible so that it helps other e.g `keyof`, `typeof`. Why you choose this solution(assigning in variable)? Use cases of `keyof`, `typeof`. One thing I like to share assigning in variable helps editor to type hint & validate data where using array directly doesn't validate mistakenly typed key.

Answer (score 2):

Also this works for me.

```
const person = {
  first: 'John',
  last: 'Doe',
  id: 1,
};


(['first', 'last']).forEach((i) => {
  delete person[i as keyof typeof person]
})
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBADgUwE4XDAvDA3gKBjAMwEsUoAuGAcgCkQALMSgGjxgBsBDaCygERATNWRACYUAjCwC%20AbhzyAFAG1KxUsyqdolALoBKAHQEQSAKIdgdBQqJ6MAPmysRCNgigJ4yVGCVEYXDAA1ggAniAEMFChiBFeKOA6OFJ6QA)

But one problem here it doesn't validate keys exist or not. So if someone mistakenly types a wrong key it will ignore e.g

```
const person = {
  first: 'John',
  last: 'Doe',
  id: 1,
};


(['first', 'lasts']).forEach((i) => {
  delete person[i as keyof typeof person]
})
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const person = {
  first: 'John',
  last: 'Doe',
  id: 1,
};


(['first', 'last'] as Array<keyof typeof person>).forEach((i) => {
  delete person[i]
})
```

you need to typecast `i` of forEach as key type of person object.

Answer (score 1):

Using `keyof typeof person` works but there is a simpler way (since TypeScript 3.4): using [const assertion](https://mariusschulz.com/blog/const-assertions-in-literal-expressions-in-typescript):

```
const person = {
  first: 'John',
  last: 'Doe',
  id: 1,
};

(['first', 'last'] as const).forEach(key => delete person[key]);
```

Indeed, `['first', 'last']` alone has type `string[]` but `as const` its type is `readonly ["first", "last"]`, a readonly tuple of string literals which are compatible with the keys of the `person` object.

We also have to pay attention to the fact that the type of the `person` object is changed after deletes. It's now `Omit<typeof person, 'first' | 'last'>` i.e. just `{ id: number }`. We can also choose a common type `{ id: number; first?: string; last?: string }` to indicate that `first` and `last` are optional fields.

Comment: Thanks nice explanation ️️️